# iOS 8 Game Center LogIn Orientation

Tags: ios, ios8, orientation, presentviewcontroller

I am trying to integrate Game Center into my game.
   So I receive the the viewcontroller from the game center and I present it.

My game is only landscape but when i launch the game the Game Center login is in portrait.
 My game's viewcontroller has **supportedOrientations** and **preferredOrientation** return only **landscape** and **shouldAutorotate** is set to **Yes;** Info plist countains also only landscape.

When I print in the xCode console the prefered orientation for the viewcontroller i receive from the gamecenter, it says portrait.
   This happens only at launch and only on iOS 8: game is landscape, gamecenter is portrait, dispite the fact that infoplist and game viewcontroller's orientation is only landscape.

I want my GameCenter to be also landscape and I've trying using:

**

```
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];
```

**
and it works but it will get rejected by Apple since it forces the orientation.
   I've also tryed using **modalPresentationStyle** setted to **UIModalPresentationCurrentContext** but it didn't work.

Any more ideas ? please, I'm desperate :P

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In my case, this is how I solved this problem:

```
gcLoginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

gcLoginViewController is the UIViewController you receive in the localPlayer's authenticateHandler.
I also made sure that **supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow** in the app's delegate returns only landscape.
It worked fine with ios 8.1.1 & 8.1.2 on 2 different devices.